# Docker Mysql container root password [mysqld listens port 0]

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

Today I'm trying to make my Docker environment working !

In this matter I've encountered quite a problem : my MySQL container, extending the MySQL official Docker image, seems to fail to create the root account, despite the setting of the `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` environment variable in my `` docker-compose`.yml ``.

I copy here my Docker files :

**docker-compose.yml**

Most of the environment variables are used in scripts and applications independantly from the MySQL server. Only `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` deserves interest (perhaps this statement is the cause of my failure to make this work..! ).

```
mysql:
    container_name: my_mysql
    build: mysql
    environment:
        - MYSQL_DATABASES=my-database
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
        - MYSQL_HOST=127.0.0.1
        - MYSQL_PORT=33306
        - MYSQL_USER=user
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
        - MYSQL_MY_DATABASE=my-database
    ports:
        - "33306:3306"
    volumes:
        - "./volumes/mysql:/var/lib/mysql"
```

**mysql/Dockerfile**

The dos2unix command is meant to convert Windows line endings to Unix.

The custom entrypoint is named differently to avoid overidding the default mysql entrypoint script.

```
FROM mysql:5.7
MAINTAINER Wonderful Dev <wonderful.dev@wonderful-company.com>

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y dos2unix

COPY conf.d/custom.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/
COPY docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/databases.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/databases.sh
COPY my-entrypoint.sh /my-entrypoint.sh

RUN dos2unix /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/databases.sh && dos2unix /my-entrypoint.sh && dos2unix /etc/mysql/conf.d/custom.cnf && apt-get --purge remove -y dos2unix && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN chmod a+x /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/databases.sh && chown root:root /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/databases.sh
RUN chmod a+x /my-entrypoint.sh && chown root:root /my-entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh", "/my-entrypoint.sh"]

CMD ["mysqld"]
```

#### mysql/my-entrypoint.sh

This chmod command is meant to avoid [this kind of error](http://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=323455)

```
#!bin/bash

chmod 664 /etc/mysql/conf.d/custom.cnf

exec "$@"
```

#### mysql/config/custom.cnf

```
[mysqld]
default-storage-engine=INNODB
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci
bind-address        = 0.0.0.0
skip-external-locking
key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M
```

All this stuff is working, except that I haven't any root access, blocking me from creating databases or mysql users for my apps !

Thank you for any advice :D !

**EDIT**: After days of investigation, and an issue in `docker-library/mysql` repository, we found out that one of the problems was a deprecated configuratio key in **custom.cnf**.

```
key_buffer => key_buffer_size
```

Now the container runs a few seconds after building, then crash.

The main clue in the logs is that line :

```
Version: '5.7.15'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

I already tried a proposed solution to configure manually the port in **custom.cnf** but it does not work. The container tries to connect to MySQL and crash due to the port.

The problem was not pretty visible because when launching the container a second time, the initialization was skipped, the good port was configured, and the server worked fine.

The thing is that due to the crash, the end of the initialization was not executed, including my scripts and the databases creation along with users.

So I'd like to find out why this damn mysqld is listening on port 0 the first time I launch the container after building.

If you have a clue, I'd be glad to here about it !

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Finally I figured it out, thanks to the guys on this issue : https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/82

The culprit was the `MYSQL_HOST` environment variable, which was causing the `mysqld --initialize-insecure` command fail.

The solution is to replace `127.0.0.1` with `localhost`, which produces the following **docker-compose.yml** :

```
mysql:
    container_name: my_mysql
    build: mysql
    environment:
        - MYSQL_DATABASES=my-database
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
        - MYSQL_HOST=localhost
        - MYSQL_PORT=33306
        - MYSQL_USER=user
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
        - MYSQL_MY_DATABASE=my-database
    ports:
        - "33306:3306"
    volumes:
        - "./volumes/mysql:/var/lib/mysql"
```

I hope it will help some people :D !

Comment: Perfect! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Try reversing your entrypoints:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/my-entrypoint.sh", "/entrypoint.sh"]
```

The builtin entrypoint is looking for "mysqld" as the first arg, not "my-entrypoint.sh". So you want to call yours and then spin up the default entrypoint with the passed options.

Comment: I tried it but the container status after it is ``exit 1`` ! I removed my ``CMD`` instruction at the end of my Dockerfile, but this time the container exited with status 0. I tried to remove the ``exec "$@"`` instruction in my entrypoint, same result. Ty for suggestion !

EDIT : I'd like to precise that in any case the logs were empty :(

Comment: It's rather difficult to debug remotely without any output or logs.